# Custom render with unobtrusive validation, dont work, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to do a little render framework, since I need some more control over the render process. Fx. if a  property need to be rendered in a tab.

So I set out to, render a TextBox, but it does not validate with server side or client side validation (the MVC unobtrusive validation)

I have taken my framework out, and recreated a little eksampel

```
  public class Foo
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    }
```

My extension method:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DummyForm(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Type oftype = typeof(Foo); 
        string[] propertyNameToRender = oftype.GetProperties().Select(o => o.Name).ToArray();

        foreach (string s in propertyNameToRender)
        {
            MvcHtmlString htmlstring = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(html, s);
            sb.AppendLine(htmlstring.ToHtmlString());
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

And on the Edit.cshtml

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    @Html.DummyForm() 
}
```

If I look at the rendered html output, its the same (without the validation attri)
Can anyone tell me, why the validation attri, is not rendered.

Im using the mvc's own render controls, HtmlHelper is passed from the view, with all ModelMetadata and ModelState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try to create a new ASP.net MVC site, and added the code from my RenderProject, and it works fine. The conclusion is my asp.net MVC project messed up. I dont why. :S

Answer (score 2):

Unobtrusive validation `data-val-*` attributes are rendered when `FormContext` is initialized. `Html.BeginForm` does that, so

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.DummyForm() 
}
```

Should render inputs with validation attributes.

Comment: Hi
I have tryed that also. Same result.
I have edit my top post, so you can se my form context.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that seems odd is that you are calling `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox` method yourself. This method is internally called by `Html.TextBox` and other strongly typed extensions. plz try changing

```
MvcHtmlString htmlstring = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(html, s);
```

to

```
MvcHtmlString htmlstring = html.TextBox(s);
```

Comment: I need more control over the rendering, when I pass in a model, i need to be enable to render one property as a dropdown, one as a intput and many I need to render it in a tab. That form of control, is not in the MVC framework now, or am I missing something ?

So I what to do the calling of the Render method, but I what to say to the framework, I need this put box type and I what it in this tab (jquery). Hope that make sens to you  :)